# php mysql_query won't find index

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a property profile page for a real estate site. For some reason it wont check the index in the database to see if it is the same value as the `?id=` in the address bar. When I use the code `select * from properties` it doesn't show any error but when I add `WHERE index='$prop_id'` it kills the page and echo's query error. The database connection file is included at the top off the `index.php` page. Can anyone help?

[image: phpMyAdmin]

```
    <?php 
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $prop_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])or die("get error");

            $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM properties WHERE index='$prop_id'") or die("query error");

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: What does `$prop_id` equal? As an aside, the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, have a look at `mysqli` instead.

Comment: I believe the query is vulnerable to SQL injections?

Comment: could careless at this point in development

Comment: Was the problem solved?

Comment: Yes but now when I put in ?id=1 it doesn't see it in the database

Comment: when I do

    echo mysql_num_rows($check)

it returns zero even thought there is an entry with that index.

Answer (score 3):

`index` is a [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/keywords.html). Fix the errors in the query. Missing `'` -

```
"SELECT * FROM properties WHERE `index` = '$prop_id'"
```

Comment: sorry I made a typo when moving the code over the quote at the end of prop_id was there already

Comment: Also added the backticks?

Answer (score 0):

Try as below :

```
"SELECT * FROM properties WHERE `index` = ".$prop_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot one single quote in the query. Please replace your query with the following:

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM properties WHERE index='".$prop_id."'") or die("query error");
```